# import cv2: importError: dlopen... reason: image not found

Tags: python, opencv, importerror, core-image

I get the following error when trying to import cv2. I installed opencv-python using pip, and also using homebrew, but I keep getting this issue. Additional info: I'm working on OSX 10.10.5, python3.6 and sublimeText3.

```
from .cv2 import *
```

> ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage
>   Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavcodec.57.107.100.dylib
>   Reason: image not found

Does anyone know why the machine can't find this CoreImage, and how I can change it?

Comment: shouldn't it be `from cv2 import *` ?? also, normally you do `import cv2` to work with opencv

Comment: hey thx for your respons, but that is acutally the code i am running, the error message includes the period, but I run import cv2. Any other ideas?

Comment: Also i forgot to mention that i'm working on a virtualenv that might make a difference too?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `from cv2 import *`

Notice no `.` before `cv2`.

OpenCV is a pretty large library so it would probably make more sense to just have `import cv2` as it might get confusing if your code gets quite long.

Comment: Interestingly that is acutally what i do. i run import cv2, and then the terminalview returns that error using import .cv2...

Comment: what is the terminal command you run that produces the error?

Comment: I have linked sublimeText to SublimeREPL, so i simply hit cmd+enter on a line of code, which then is executed. The code i ran was 'import cv2'

Comment: Could be something to do with the SublimeREPL or the installation. Maybe try saving the file as a `.py` and then running it from the terminal with `python file.py` and see if you get an error.